# nested ternary cannot get local variable, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Edit Note: This referred to question does not actually solve my first problem, it was a matter of an extra {} around first ternary result. I replaced them with parenthesis.  Josep's solution using getTime I ended up needing to equate the dates.  the Date().setHours(0,0,0,0) I used on the real time date to equate to the user generated date which has 0 as hours, minutes, seconds, then .getTime()

Why can't `hour` access the `const hour = this.state.date.getHours()` of (state date = new Date()) inside constructor of the component, when I put it in the date === ternary?  the hour nested ternary gets hour when on it's own in the jsx of react component. `new Date(this.state.year, this.state.month, this.state.day)` is used as the day selected by the user that sets state when the user selects it - so if it equals the current `date`, I want to render the image `clockbordermoon` or `clockbordersun` in the nested ternary.

I've tried a nested ternary inside an if statement's render but still couldn't reach `hour`

```
  {date === new Date(this.state.year, this.state.month, this.state.day) ?
    {hour === 20 ||
    hour === 21 ||
    hour === 22 ||
    hour === 23 ||
    hour === 0 ||
    hour === 1 ||
    hour === 2 ||
    hour === 3 ||
    hour === 4 ? (
      <img
        src={clockbordermoon}
        className="clockborder"
        style={{
          transform: `translate(-50%, -50%)rotate(${totaldegrees}deg)`
        }}
        alt="error"
      />
    ) : (
      <img
        src={clockbordersun}
        className="clockborder"
        style={{
          transform: `translate(-50%, -50%)rotate(${totaldegrees}deg)`
        }}
        alt="error"
      />
    )}
    : null}
```

how can I get `hour` to read `const hour = this.state.date.getHours()`, which is inside render before the divs & imgs?

this is my second question today, I should be set for a while after this one, sorry

full code (tentatively):  https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-dijkstra-1c31n?fontsize=14 this component is src>UIConainers>Calendar>CalSlideDrawer.js, found by top-left logo icon (after pressing the inbox icon if you're starting on the purple screen)

Edit (error Unexpected token, expected "," after first hour was because I didn't need the brackets around the first result of the ternary):

```
class CalSlideDrawer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date(),
      day: new Date().getDate(),
      month: +new Date().getMonth() + 1,
      year: +new Date().getFullYear(),
    };
  }
//statefor 
   const monthname = Object.keys(CALENDAR_MONTHS)[
      Math.max(0, Math.min(month - 1, 11))
    ].toUpperCase();
   const weekdayname = new Date(this.state.year, this.state.month, this.state.day);
   const hour = this.state.date.getHours();
    return (
      {date.getTime() === weekdayname.getTime() ?
        (hour === 20 ||
        hour === 21 ||
        hour === 22 ||
        hour === 23 ||
        hour === 0 ||
        hour === 1 ||
        hour === 2 ||
        hour === 3 ||
        hour === 4 ? (
          <img
            src={clockbordermoon}
          />
        ) : (
          <img
            src={clockbordersun}
          />
        )): null}
```

Comment: Why not just use `if/else` blocks? My rule of thumb is if the ternary is more than three lines, it should probably go into a block...

Comment: I think ternaries are less code so if I can get the variable from within the nested ternary from it being defined in render before the divs & imgs, then I'll use it, if I can't I'll try if again but that didn't work when I tried it last so I think the issue is with hour,... or as Josep says maybe it's just because I didn't instantiate new Date() before using it to compare in a ternary

Comment: You may want to consider putting parentheses around all of those hour comparisons, or use an array (e.g., `[20,21,22,23,0,1,2,3,4].includes(hour)`). Also, I haven't used React that much, but I'm not sure you need all of the curly brackets... Finally, "less code" ranks below "understandable code" in most professional settings.

Comment: I think ternaries are just easier to read and they're less code.  I'll try/research includes later but now I just want it to work

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand your question or what you are trying to do, but please notice that the following expression will always evaluate to false:

```
date === new Date(this.state.year, this.state.month, this.state.day)
```

because you are comparing a newly created reference with something else. For instance, this evaluates to `false`:

```js
console.log(
  (new Date(2015,5,5)) === (new Date(2015,5,5))
)
```

And this evaluates to `true`:

```js
    console.log(
      (new Date(2015,5,5)).getTime() === (new Date(2015,5,5)).getTime()
    )
```

Perhaps the problem has to do with the way that your are comparing the dates?

Comment: you are saying I have to instantiate `new Date(this.state.year, this.state.month, this.state.day)` in a variable first before I `date` (which is an instantiated new Date()) === `new Date(this.state.year, this.state.month, this.state.day)` like `date===usersdate`?

Comment: I edited the question with a better version of the code so you know where everything comes from, sorry about that, instantiating new Date() first before using it in ternary still same error `Unexpected token, expected "," after first hour`

Comment: Might want to read this (and the duplicate question's answers) again. Basically, you can't compare `Date` objects with `==` or `===` because they do object reference comparisons, not value comparisons. Use `getTime()` as shown here, or `valueOf()`...

Comment: the same error is produced `Unexpected token, expected ","` for first hour...`{date.getTime() === weekdayname.getTime() ?
        {hour === 20 ||
        hour === 21 
         ? (
          <img
            src={clockbordermoon}
          />
        ) : (
          <img
            src={clockbordersun}
          />
        )}: null}`

Comment: I'm going to leave my codesandbox on the error page for you for the early evening

Comment: It gave the same error at the hour variable regardless if .getTime is used... usually if there is a problem with two things the first would showcase the error. with or without get time it says the same error, after the first ternary. that can't be the problem